# "Discoursed of"

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

**[SOURCE](http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00002)**    (Sir Isaac Newton)

> - An hypothesis explaining the properties of light, ***discoursed*** ***of*** ***in*** my several papers.

I looked it up the dictionary and I found that ***discoursed*** couldn't be followed by a preposition except ***on*** and ***upon***.

So, how could you grammatically describe this case and give me the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: In that case, you should consult other dictionaries. When Sir Isaac Newton wrote this in 1675, _discourse_ commonly took the preposition _of_. Today, the usage is uncommon, but it would not be unacceptable, however quaint it might sound to a modern reader. _Discoursed of_ here means _expounded on_.

Comment: It's unidiomatic today: most of us would use *discussed in several papers of mine.* And it's ambiguous: it's not clear whether the papers dealt with the hypothesis or with the properties of light.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I consulted most of known dictionaries, and I didn't find this phrase. Maybe it is unidiomatic as StoneyB, so it has been removed from dictionaries.

Comment: The _Oxford English Dictionary_, which is surely "known", has:  "**b.** _intr._ Frequently with _of, on, upon._ To speak or write (in later use at length or formally) on a particular topic. Cf. DISCOURSE _n._ 3a. Also without construction: to hold forth, pronounce, sermonize." This usage even today will be readily understood by native English speakers of a certain level of erudition, although even they may consider it quaint or archaic. Nevertheless it is perfectly sound English.

Comment: But i didn't even find ***discourse*** with **of** in oxford dictionary. I did not understand about what you mean by. Has b frequently with of , and 3a ? @P. D. Dant

Comment: "Oxford Dictionary" is not the same as the OED or "**O**xford **E**nglish **D**ictionary". By "has", I meant "provides as a definition". The definition that follows is enclosed in quotation marks. The **b** is their (the OED's) notation for the second in a series of definitions marked **a**, **b**, **c**, etc. When Sir Isaac Netwon wrote that description in 1675, it was common to say _discourse **of**_. It is far less common today. "..discoursed of" means the same thing as "discussed" or "expounded upon".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not concerned with a modern dialect of English.

Comment: @JamesK On that theory, we must not expect learners of English to be able to read Shakespeare or the Bill of Rights.

Comment: No, its more nuanced than that.  I would not expect learners to use Shakespeare or the bill of rights as learning materials. Anyway lots of native speakers don't understand shakespeare (but can still enjoy his plays)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're not finding "discoursed of" in the dictionary is because most dictionaries focus on present-day English (and yes, this does make it hard to read older works). "Discoursed of" isn't really used now, but it was used back in Newton's time. You can find plenty of examples in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discoursed+of%22&biw=1440&bih=726&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1750&tbm=bks).

The [OED](http://oed.com), as a historical dictionary (that unfortunately requires a subscription), has the relevant definition of *discourse*:

> *intr.* Frequently with *of*, *on*, *upon*. To speak or write (in later use at length or formally) on a particular topic

In other words, Newton was saying he already wrote about his hypothesis in some of his other papers.